# Lévy’s Characterization of Brownian Motion Proof

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I am trying to understand the proof of Levy's characterization: we define the process $Y$ by $Y_t = \exp(iuM_t+\frac{1}{2}u^2t)$ where $u\in\mathbb{R}$ arbitrary and $M_t$ a continous local martingale starting at $0$ with quadratic variation $t$.

Now it should hold by applying Ito's formula, that $Y_t = 1+iu\int_0^t Y_s dM_s$, which I don't understand. To apply Ito's formula we need a twice differentiable function, in our case $f(x,t)=\exp(iux+\frac{1}{2}u^2t)$. Since $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ we use the generalized Ito formula, which says:
$$f(X_t) = f(X_0) + \sum_{i=1}^d \int_0^t \frac{d}{dx_i} f(X)dX_i+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^d\int_0^t\frac{d^2}{dx_idx_j}f(X)d\langle X_i,X_j\rangle,$$
where $X$ is a $d$-dimensional vector of semimartingales (I have already shown that the formula holds if $f$ maps to $\mathbb{C}$). We then get
\begin{align}
Y_t &= 1+iu\int_0^t Y_s dM_s+\frac{1}{2}u^2\int_0^tY_sds + \frac{1}{2}\left(-u^2\int_0^t Y_sds + \frac{1}{4}u^4\int_0^tY_sds + iu^3\int_0^t Y_sd\langle M,t\rangle_s \right)\\
&= 1 + iu\int_0^t Y_sdM_s + \frac{1}{8}u^4\int_0^tY_sds + iu^3\int_0^t d\langle M,t\rangle_s
\end{align}
if everything is correct. From this point I dont't know how to go on. I tried to calculate the quadratic covariation $\langle M,t\rangle$ but wasn't able to or maybe there was a mistake in the previous equation? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You mean $Y_t=1+iu\int_0^tY_sdM_s$?

Comment: yes, i will edit it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We suppose $\langle M,M\rangle_t=t$ so we have
$$df(M_t,t)=f_t(M_t,t)dt+f_x(M_t,t)dM_t+\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(M_t,t)\underbrace{d\langle M,M\rangle_t}_{dt}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}&f(x,t)=e^{iu x+\frac{1}{2}u^2t}\\
&f_t(x,t)=u^2f(x,t)/2\\
&f_x(x,t)=iuf(x,t)\\
&f_{xx}(x,t)=-u^2f(x,t)\end{aligned}$$
so if $Y_t=f(X_t,t)$ we get
$$dY_t=\frac{1}{2}u^2Y_tdt+iu Y_tdM_t+\frac{1}{2}(-u^2)Y_tdt=iuY_tdt\implies Y_t=1+iu\int_0^tY_sdM_s$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't understand where the first equation comes from. $f_tdt+f_xdM_t$ on the right handside are coming from the first sum of the generalized ito formula. But i don't understand how the second sum reduces to $1/2f_{xx}dt$

Comment: @bumbummath you may note $t \mapsto t$ is a continuous process with bounded variation, thus a semimartingale; we consider $(M_t,t)$. Also, the quadratic covariation of a semimartingale and of a continuous process with bounded variation is zero.

Comment: @bumbummath if you want a direct reference for the formula: Karatzas, Shreve; Th.3.6. p.  153